# NGNIX reverse proxy settings

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

i've successfully managed to set up a reverse proxy which receives data via POST requests from clients and forwards them to a NodeJS server for further processing and storing.

now i would like the nginx reverse proxy to return a 200 OK blank response for all of these requests BEFORE forwarding to the nodeJS server. so the clients will receive the response immediately without the need to wait for the backend server to finish the processing.
if i use "return 202;" inside the location directive, the nginx reverse proxy does respond immediately, but never forwards the request to the NodeJS server.

can this be achieved with nginx?
any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried chunked response? http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/chunked_encoding_from_backend.html